# textview inside a scrollview not filling the height of screen

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, android-relativelayout

In my activity I have 2 text views. I need to stretch the height of the textview2 to fill the screen . My textview is inside the relativelayout with scrollview as root. Even I mentioned as match_parent It is not filling the screen but taking as wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" 
    tools:context=".CoupansActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/back_ground">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="COUPONS" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="fill"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
       android:background="@drawable/back"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Some text" />
</RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What about fill_parent? Should do the job.

Comment: @sandkasten `fill_parent` is deprecated in favor of `match_parent` since API 8.

Comment: Oh, last apps I created was all for API 7, so don't know about this change ^^

Comment: I need the scrollview in landscape mode to see the entire content in the textview. So please send me the answer by using scrollview.

Comment: so how is it now,... i mean, how could you make the textview's height become fill_parent of the scrollview @user2201685 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" 
    tools:context=".CoupansActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/back_ground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="COUPONS" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
       android:background="@drawable/back"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Some text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If all you have in the layout is two `TextView`s I don't think the `ScrollView` is necessary.

Comment: I need the scrollview in landscape mode to see the entire content in the textview. So please send me the answer by using scrollview. –

Comment: @user2201685 do you need both `TextView` to be scrolling or just one?

Comment: @TronicZomB, ... seems the textview under that scrolview doesn't make a different....

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this should work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp" 
tools:context=".CoupansActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/back_ground">

<ScrollView 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="COUPONS" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
   android:background="@drawable/back"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Some text" />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry! it wont work as scrollview can have only one child inside it.. but I have 2 textviews

Answer (score 0):

```
   .... <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" 
        tools:context=".CoupansActivity" 
        android:background="@drawable/back_ground">....
```

remove the folowing and you will have better results :

```
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for your ScrollView:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Ref: [Android scrollview not filling parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444867/android-scrollview-not-filling-parent-view)