# Android scrollview not filling parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, view, scrollview

I have the following layout that contains a scrollview. After screen sizes greater than around 4.8" there is a white area at the bottom of the view. Why is this, when i have specified the scrollview to fill_parent?

Thanks in advance.

NB you can't see the white space below the menu on the screenshot below as it's white, sorry. There is a bout a n inch or 2 of space

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >



    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/carefreebgscaledlighting"
        android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textviewcompanyname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#003F87" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewYouAreSignedIn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#003F87"
             />

              <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUnsentTransactions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewYouAreSignedIn"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#003F87"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spacerasnexttextviewclasheswithbg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
             />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imagesignaltower"
                android:background="@drawable/signaltower"/>

            <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarSignal"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/stringloggedinscreen"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#003F87" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsignin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/stringbuttonsignin"
         />

.........
...........
...........
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

.

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

add to your `ScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Good, keep that in mind. The child (Scrollview can only hold one child) will expand to same size as the ScrollView.

Answer (score 9):

try to set `ScrollView` `android:fillViewport="true"` , refer to [**this**](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Answer (score 5):

Just use this :

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Example ScrollView :

```
<ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
                    >
```

Example NestedScrollView :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
                    >
```